# Freemarker image not displaying in emails base64 - Java

Tags: java, freemarker

Image displays in web browser fine as base64 but when I send it via email it does not show.

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/conf/app-core/logo.png";
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);
byte[] data = new byte[0];

data = Files.readAllBytes(path);


byte[] encoded = java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(data);
String imgDataAsBase64 = new String(encoded);
String imgAsBase64 = "data:image/png;base64," + imgDataAsBase64;

map.put("logo", imgAsBase64);
```

The template looks like this:

```
<img alt="Logo"  src="${logo}" />
```

The source of the email looks as follows:

```
<img alt="logo"  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAAAXCAYAAAD9VOo7AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAA3JpVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u/IiBpZD0iVzVNME1wQ2VoaUh6cmVTek5UY3prYzlkIj8+IDx4OnhtcG1ldGEgeG1sbnM6eD0iYWRvYmU6bnM6bWV0YS8iIHg6eG1wdGs9IkFkb2JlIFhNUCBDb3JlIDUuNi1jMDY3IDc5LjE1Nzc0NywgMjAxNS8wMy8zMC0yMzo0MDo0MiAgICAgICAgIj4gPHJkZjpSREYgeG1sbnM6cmRmPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5LzAyLzIyLXJkZi1zeW50YXgtbnMjIj4gPHJkZjpEZXNjcmlwdGlvbiByZGY6YWJvdXQ9IiIgeG1sbnM6eG1wTU09Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC9tbS8iIHhtbG5zOnN0UmVmPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hhcC8xLjAvc1R5cGUvUmVzb3VyY2VSZWYjIiB4bWxuczp4bXA9Imh0dHA6Ly9ucy5hZG9iZS5jb20veGFwLzEuMC8iIHhtcE1NOk9yaWdpbmFsRG9jdW1lbnRJRD0ieG1wLmRpZDpmN2FhZjg1NS1iZTdkLTRlNGUtYjU4Zi1mNjIwYTU4NDMwYWQiIHhtcE1NOkRvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6NTc4NTk0NDAyRDUyMTFFODlENEFFRDg1NTAwRDU1RUQiIHhtcE1NOkluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6NTc4NTk0M0YyRDUyMTFFODlENEFFRDg1NTAwRDU1RUQiIHhtcDpDcmVhdG9yVG9vbD0iQWRvYmUgUGhvdG9zaG9wIENDIDIwMTUgKFdpbmRvd3MpIj4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0UmVmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6N2RlY2VhZTgtMzMxMy00MTRhLWJlMWItYjY0YzhlMmUzNTNiIiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjc0RjE0OUYyMzRCMzExRTdCRDUzQTYzRUI0MjRENEIxIi8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpSREY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+dwoOfQAABhhJREFUeNrsmntM1lUYx3khQEIuCl4wkC5YYmW52QWHq2yKkdMtK6d2WXZxzVZ0YbRyarbWypZpbkYrXcjKmJmVriyN7KKSLsTMIrRIDeUiKCZ4g7fv476/+XR2fj9eXl7/6n22D7/z+53785zLc86Lz+/3R4TlvMgIcBlYDToDzXRBWG8hl+HgaZABHuyOMcIGCZ2IHnPBOPAMaAA3gz+DKSgsPZPx4A5wmsuU6PQ+sCeAvCNBb/BN2CA9l6vB6zTEVjADZIKvSSAis6lJGyQyrNduSx+wEOwE1aAMFNIYIpu6UZbf3GNsMySB3kEC18I/OAq6khQ2Kh4cAbXgmEvaKJAOBnFQNDB9V/VIu64AJ8GvoM6Iv5BxHVScs4RUgXojbRo34NOMPxxAHyeCxeznXLAFfAZiVZpqPnuBE+zrVVyadoDjDLeBaBADfCDxbLvF7SVxYA7Y7z8nHaASTFTpTK4FZaDJ/1+pBxMs6aeDCtCu0p4CO8EjINKSJwWsAnvBZlAFWkCRShMNysEoMIXlbeGzETym0r4E9oCtLOsgeNSjj73AEtXe5eAS9tEU0cdTYAFIAuvBblAL7mF5q0ENOAoOg5/ZtzKnwgSwQRW6D/wEjqlv91oaOg2cMBTbANr4XqDSRrEjWpqpWC3vWurZCNaCvnz3gRvAZJUmhoPnPfAFuFzF5YEjIB+8QkNdrOJvo3LGW+oeADap9smA7Q/WWIwh/U+jwUvAh+A59l0GfB+WKXWns08rwCAwFGQ6lS5Vhc4GsfyeRcOIHGBDnDw3qlEuM+kNkA2SQQYo5Eh10s9VdfxCJcnIT6Vi9cycpfKN4Agf7DGCnRlSzdE+0BJfQKV/x5Frxr8G1hnfEjkjtczkLLTJISpfdHiGffZq8/tgkf4mf3JAKwsssWQapyqcob6vVd8LXSr08ZlGpfr5HGJJewsN6xgsht9zmadfAAYRo77qEp+tFGqLv53LSIz6ttRQuBg7HixzMch25nsBdHIWeLX5A/Cm/iYb6t3cwEVW8RlPYrhJtfD79XxeyoOPyC6wyMOLiOChKZXhlaDGkrYc/MCwbNxDGa6kc/BkFxuubIynwDaX+BY6D5Uu8Ye4EcerNs800qziZjzGpYwdakOX8IHuunCRPJw48hbYB34je6mkROWZiGSphn9PRXjJMBXe5pFul/LCBjMsXsk08BDY7KEMkTMenp2f7Wxzie+kUX18f0KFHSmlx5TpUka58l5rg/GpI5VipcFJdF/7KpJBK91JpzNJqozmAOqJV+F2j3RaWdEqLAevK8GPHKXyfp3HTPGaRT6POD/7mckTuJbdoALc5JL/qHEGOR7sHUyzatBkdjbOpcEnGP5Hfb8ogHpaVLi/R7oBKtxkxDWCAjAfzONskeX24xAf/MQgY3lW0LJGLWU2WR/MEmWbIRXqPYuHuoMW6pTxqtUIGKP2BzepNO5+3GZRDsP1XDJtIm14HLxMQn3bEKX2R22kUsa5zcx3gqzPbxqkTCm6CGRbMsVxr3E6L6f3rxjO4Ok11siTSgM71wnO/jCB+4EpRTyJR/A3hMYuOrKBe1tCCI3RyTJNHXzEm4FRdGhM+VLpo8fXxnJt8DZ4ltcZ34ISsJ0NHAKmczqOVXmfV97TVHANG15HIz0AFvDep53lf8JRVgzyuQnKe56aOb+DF1U9/XgVYu5VMor3c+0OlXRw30wzZuR8hqe4LHFzgqzvb+VNcr6c8+GL/d6y3OJH59B3d5OHjfR3qvOITTbzMBphnLLlUDqPYTlVL+a1xWiVLpZtyXfx+eUsVAeGu8SPBH/x6dwenASTGJ/u0vbZlrLksLeyizOIU2cr+ya6KfAZP+GKB3EXzwGx9K5qOB03cjSYksg8t/KysJMun2xyn1q8qoEcabncxE9zCVwHPrfUId7W/dzA+6iLxYX0fPTaP4tl2M45vXmuKLVcNDou/WQuhdvpQk9leSJLWL6WFfztw5Q87omrA5gl+TxjxZx1HAKw4v+NFN6HDVPfJrmsGNGhrt8X/icHzzOJyGjO9GS+N3DPKD4vFYcN4imy9Czj7yxV/O3DbckLifwrwAA4KctId+YfSgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

If I use a base64 online converter the image is generated correctly from the above.  The image does not display in any email program however.  It just shows either the alt message (in gmail) or an X (in outlook)

Comment: Update:  The image shows on my iPhone email fine but not in other clients

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with FreeMarker. Apparently, many e-mail clients don't support `data:` images... I heard about this elsewhere already.

Comment: What kind of mail client do you use ?